# Setting the width/height inside HTML differs from what happens in CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css, canvas, height

I am having a lot of confusion trying to figure out what is happening. I am drawing some boxes in  using javaScript. I am following this guide to recreate breakout.

[Breakout Tutorial](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Games/Tutorials/2D_Breakout_game_pure_JavaScript/Create_the_Canvas_and_draw_on_it)

The trouble that I am having is that the canvas size does not work if I am using external css to set the width heigth like so below, the css doesnt work.

```
#myCanvas{
width: "480";
height: "320";
}
```

However if I change the code to in my html to this

```
    <canvas id = "myCanvas" width ="480" height="320">    
</canvas>
```

The box is the right size. Why cant I set the height and width out of the html?

[Here is a JSfiddle of the box with the right size.](https://jsfiddle.net/end3r/x62h15e2/)

If you move the css width/height over to the external side it doesn't work anymore. What gives?

Answer (score 0):

There is a difference between inline tags (id, class, width, height, style, ...) and css attributes (width, height, font-size, ...).

If you want to use the css attributes width and height you need the remove the "" and add the unit.

e.g.

```
#myCanvas{
  width: 480px;
  height: 320px;
}
```

You can also add css inline using the style attribute:

```
<canvas id = "myCanvas" style = "width: 480px; height: 320px">
```

Comment: This isn't working. Can you take a look at this jsfiddle with your suggestion? as you will notice the shapes are messed, they look like they got larger.

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/barboa91/mbwhLvf8/2/#&togetherjs=J7m4SD1170)

Answer (score 0):

A canvas has 2 sizes, the dimension of the pixels in the canvas (it's backingstore or drawingBuffer) and the display size.

The number of pixels is set using the the canvas attributes in HTML.

```
<canvas id = "myCanvas" style = "width: 480px; height: 320px">
```

which is separate from width and height that are in canvas's CSS style.

```
myCanvas{ width: 480px;  height: 320px;
```

Changed your code to understand better.

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

ctx.beginPath();
ctx.rect(10, 10, 30, 20);
ctx.fillStyle = "#FF0000";
ctx.fill();
ctx.closePath();

ctx.beginPath();
ctx.arc(30, 80, 20, 0, Math.PI*2, false);
ctx.fillStyle = "green";
ctx.fill();
ctx.closePath();

ctx.beginPath();
ctx.rect(10, 140, 30, 40);
ctx.strokeStyle = "rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.5)";
ctx.stroke();
ctx.closePath();
```

```css
canvas { 
         background:#eee; border:1px solid #ccc; 
         width:200px; 
         height:300px 
}
```

```html
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="100" height="200"></canvas>
```